# UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID When using apache kafka streams (scala)

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am running 3 instances of a service that I wrote using:

- Scala 2.11.12
- kafkaStreams 1.1.0
- kafkaStreamsScala 0.2.1 (by lightbend)

The service uses Kafka streams with the following topology (high level):

1. InputTopic
2. Parse to known Type
3. Clear messages that the parsing failed on
4. split every single message to 6 new messages
5. on each message run: map.groupByKey.reduce(with local store).toStream.to

Everything works as expected but i can't get rid of a WARN message that keeps showing:

```
15:46:00.065 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my_service_name-1ca232ff-5a9c-407c-a3a0-9f198c6d1fa4-StreamThread-1-0_0-producer] [WARN ] [o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender] - [Producer clientId=my_service_name-1ca232ff-5a9c-407c-a3a0-9f198c6d1fa4-StreamThread-1-0_0-producer, transactionalId=my_service_name-0_0] Got error produce response with correlation id 28 on topic-partition my_service_name-state_store_1-repartition-1, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID
```

As you can see, I get those errors from the INTERNAL topics that Kafka stream manage. Seems like some kind of retention period on the producer metadata in the internal topics / some kind of a producer id reset.

Couldn't find anything regarding this issue, only a description of the error itself from [here](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_error_codes):

```
ERROR   CODE    RETRIABLE   DESCRIPTION

UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID 59  False   This exception is raised by the broker if it could not locate the producer metadata associated with the producerId in question. This could happen if, for instance, the producer's records were deleted because their retention time had elapsed. Once the last records of the producer id are removed, the producer's metadata is removed from the broker, and future appends by the producer will return this exception.
```

Hope you can help,
Thanks

***Edit:***
It seems that the WARN message does not pop up on version 1.0.1 of kafka streams.

Comment: How old are the messages you are writing?

Comment: A couple of ms old. I produce messages from the CLI directly to the Input topic of the stream topology, and can see the error pops in less than a second or so

Comment: Ok, we're seeing the same exception, though I don't know if it is the same cause. I just registered an issue with Kafka, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6817

Comment: you are using the transactional producer, correct? we got the same thing here. In Kafka 1.0.0 this lead to failure, in 1.1.0 it's at least retrying…

Comment: in case you missed the edit: in 1.0.1 it seems to be working fine